# Can you define inductive data types over categories other than Set?

Tags: ct.category-theory, induction

Can you define inductive data types over categories other than $\mathbb{Set}$?

What does it look like? How about for a specific example like the category of monoids? If you were clever could you write a macro for inductive types other than over $\mathbb{Set}$?

Silly Coq like pseudocode here

```
MonoidalInductive tree : Set :=
| mktree : prooflistismonoid -> list tree -> tree
.
```

### Background

I was learning about well founded recursion again.

For the least upper bound $\mu$ of an endofunctor $F$ from $C$ to $C$ we have a mapping.

$$ \mathbb{map} : \mathbb{Hom}_C(a, b) \rightarrow \mathbb{Hom}_C(F a, F b)$$

And a fold

$$ \mathbb{fold} : \mathbb{Hom}_C(F a, a) \rightarrow \mathbb{Hom}_C(\mu F, a) $$

Many theorem provers provide a more pleasing built-in syntax for declaring inductive types. A simple list in Coq for example.

```
Inductive list (a : Set) : Set :=
| nil: list a
| cons: a -> list a -> list a
.
```

As I understand things this example could be viewed as defining the least upper bound of the fixed point of $\mathbb{F} \, a$ for $\mathbb{F} \, a \, x = 1 + a * x$ **within the category of $\mathbb{Set}$.**

Because these sort of inductive types take the fixed point of an endofunctor on $\mathbb{Set}$ they are required to be strictly positive and not recurse contravariantly. If these types weren't strictly positive they wouldn't be structured around endofunctors on $\mathbb{Set}$ they would be structured around somewhere other kind of functor.

So what about induction over categories other than $\mathbb{Set}$?

Coinduction for example seems to make sense as induction over the opposite category. Monoidal induction sounds to me like it might be good for working with lists.

Comment: Inductive data types are the same as [W-types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_type#W-_and_M-types), which are represented categorically by initial algebras for [polynomial functors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_functor_(type_theory)). Therefore any category with initial algebras for polynomial functors (e.g. a [W-pretopos](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pretopos)) will be able to interpret inductive types.

Comment: @varkor Can you give a specific example of a W pretopos one might take an initial algebra over different than Set?

Comment: Any topos with a natural numbers object, e.g. a [Grothendieck topos](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck+topos), is a W-pretopos. So the category of presheaves $[\mathbf C^{\mathrm{op}}, \mathrm{Set}]$ for any small category $\mathbf C$ models inductive types; or the category of sheaves over any small site.